# To push data into nested array and then send that whole data using http post method to API

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, json

Here is my json file , I want to push data into workingDay (multiple data push) & workingHours which is inside array workingSchedules.

```
    {
  "data": {
    "id": "string",
    "workingSchedules": [
      {
        "workingDay": "MONDAY",
        "workingHours": [
          {
            "fromTime": 0,
            "toTime": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "twentyFourSevenOpen": false
  },
  "dataList": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "workingSchedules": [
        {
          "workingDay": "MONDAY",
          "workingHours": [
            {
              "fromTime": 0,
              "toTime": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "twentyFourSevenOpen": false
    }
  ]
}
```

My code is like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4">Day</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">From time</th>
            <th class="col-md-4">To time</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>

       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-repeat="x in something.workingSchedules">
              <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="col-sm-4">  
                     <input style="margin-top:15px" ng-model="x.workingDay" class="form-control input-sm" id="pwd" placeholder="Timings">
                 </div>
              </div>
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-repeat="x in x.workingHours">

              <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-4" >  
                     <input ng-model="x.fromTime" class="form-control input-sm" id="pwd" placeholder="Timings">
                 </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-4">  
                     <input ng-model="x.toTime" class="form-control input-sm" id="pwd" placeholder="Timings">
                 </div>
              </div>

           </form>
         </form>

   </tbody>
```

This only allows to update a single workingSchedules object, what I want is to first push data into the array in UI and then post it to backend API using http post.

Comment: You need to upload your js method for that

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First, `workingDays` needs to be an array, the same as you have for `workingHours`.

Once you have done that, you use the following:

```
data.workingSchedules.workingDay.push('FRIDAY') ;
```

In general, I would suggest that the objects within an array are always of the form:

```
{"DayName":"MONDAY"}
```

and not just the name of the day. Your current form will work though.

Comment: If it's a single array, can he push like this `data.workingSchedules.workingDay.push("FRIDAY") ;` ?

Comment: Surely it's better to use a number to represent weekday instead of a string? For instance, in JS try doing `new Date().getDay()`, which will return `2` today as it is Tuesday.

Comment: To @A.Rossi, the answer is YES. It is just a matter of taste (as you know, you write code once but you read it millions of times, and sometimes quite long after you wrote it, so make a small effort to make it readable and maintainable). As for using numbers, you would need to remember that 0 means "SUNDAY", or perhaps "MONDAY", or perhaps 1 is "SUNDAY"...